# Can I control the overlap across panorama items?

Tags: windows-phone-7, panorama-control

I have multiple textBlocks as panorama Items. Each textBlock contains data covering the entire screen.

I see that when item1 is displayed on the screen, some of the text from item2 is also shown on the border of item1. ALso, due to this, some of the characters of item1 also get cropped.

The item1 text when normally displayed on screen using simple Phone Portrait Page gets displayed perfectly fine.

Can I somehow avoid this overlap between the panorama items?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a panorama control the left edge of the second page can be seen on the first page, I think this is by design. If you don't want this you may try the Pivot control instead.

Your item1 TextBlock should have TextWrapping set to Wrap, and the text should rather go to next line than overlap the text on page 2.

Answer (score -1):

I found out that if you use Orientation for the panorama as Horizontal and if the item in each panorama item has enough width to cover the entire phone width, then part of the second panorama item wont show up along side the first panorama item.

Thanks
-Abhinav-

Comment: But this is not the standard "Metro-UI way" way of doing things, so it's not going to be consistent with how the platform work and how users will expect apps to behave.  I'd agree with Xin that it sounds like you should be using a Pivot, not a Panorama